# MySQL query with UNION ALL gives error 1271

Tags: mysql, sql

I've various tables for storing comments of various parts of a website that have the same structure. I want to moderate the comments on the admin panel but I can't do a page for each, so I want to select it all and then LIMIT it. I asked how to do this here on SO and they solved my question but I get the error: **1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'**.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM  noticias_comentarios
                ORDER BY
                        ts_creado DESC
                LIMIT 10
                ) q
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM carruseles_comentarios
                ORDER BY
                        ts_creado DESC
                LIMIT 10
                ) q
        ) q
JOIN    usuarios u
ON      u.id = q.id_usuario
ORDER BY
        ts_creado DESC
LIMIT   0, 10
```

All the 3 tables have the character set utf8 and the collation utf8_spanish_ci.

How can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATED with the answer of Larry:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
   SELECT id, id_noticia, id_usuario, comentario, ts_creado
   FROM  noticias_comentarios
   ORDER BY ts_creado DESC
   LIMIT 0, 10
  UNION ALL
   SELECT id, id_carrusel, id_usuario, comentario, ts_creado
   FROM carruseles_comentarios
   ORDER BY  ts_creado DESC
   LIMIT 0, 10
  ) q
JOIN    usuarios u  ON u.id = q.id_usuario
ORDER BY ts_creado DESC
LIMIT   0, 10
```

Now produces the error: **1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the first ORDER BY in the queries you are UNIONing together:

> ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

You should just remove that ORDER BY and LIMIT and apply it to the results of the UNION ALL. Like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
   SELECT id, id_noticia, NULL as id_carrusel, id_usuario, comentario COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci, ts_creado
   FROM  noticias_comentarios
  UNION ALL
   SELECT id, NULL as id_noticia, id_carrusel, id_usuario, comentario, ts_creado
   FROM carruseles_comentarios
   ORDER BY  ts_creado DESC
   LIMIT 0, 10
  ) q
JOIN    usuarios u  ON u.id = q.id_usuario
ORDER BY q.ts_creado DESC
LIMIT   0, 10
```

Comment: @Ike Walker: Thank you for your reply. With that code that you posted I get another time the 1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'. If you want, I can post the sql to reproduce the error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Isern: If you run SHOW CREATE TABLE for all 3 tables and post the output it should help me determine where the problem is: `show create table noticias_comentarios\G show create table carruseles_comentarios\G show create table usuarios\G`

Comment: @Ike: Thank you in advance! The `\G` command didn't worked for me so I used `;`. I don't know if `\G` does something specific but here you've the output: http://pastebin.com/1FSmrqCX

Comment: @Isern: The problem is that the noticias_comentarios.comentario column uses the utf8_spanish2_ci collation, and the carruseles_comentarios.comentario column uses the utf8_spanish_ci collation, so you can't UNION them. You can get around that by forcing one of the columns to the other collation in the query. I'll update my answer above with an example.

Comment: @Ike: I don't understand why has been changed to utf8_spanish2_ci. In my Database Model in MySQL Workbench I've all as Default Collocation that is utf8_spanish_ci. How I can change the collocation via mysql console? Thank you! And yes, it works! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Ike: One more thing. In my query result I see that id_noticia and id_carrusel has been merged, so I can't identify where they're from. My idea for this Query is to manage the comments of all website in the backend. I'll add some JOINs like `noticias.name where noticias.id = noticias_comentarios.id_noticia` (not exactly code, I know) but I've to know where they're from to identify it with PHP and then link to /news/<slug>/#comment-id or /carrusel/<slug>/#comment-id for example. How I can manage this? Thank you another time! :)

Comment: @Isern: Somebody changed the collation for that column so it overrides the table's collation. You can change it back like this: `ALTER TABLE noticias_comentarios MODIFY COLUMN comentario text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL;`

Comment: As for differentiating between id_noticia and id_carrusel, you can just add an extra column to each select, and select NULL for the id that is not relevent. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Totally fantastic, why I can vote you up x3? I'm trying to add a third table with this code: http://pastebin.com/20iMSJGP . And I get NULL for id_noticia and id_carrusel and full ids for id_grada. Your code works perfectly. What I'm doing wrong now? I've reproduced exactly your code. Thank you.. another time!

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. It just happens that the first 10 rows based on your ORDER BY all come from the desdelagrada_comentarios table.

Comment: Right, my fault. Fantastic. Thank you. You solved me a big problem! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ouch.  Things that strike me at first glance:

- I don't believe you need all those nested result sets.
- You are reusing the alias "q" for several different queries.
- You should not use SELECT * in UNIONs.  You should specify which columns you want, and in which order (and they must match in the different result sets you UNION together).

Try the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
   (SELECT col1, col2. . .
   FROM  noticias_comentarios
   ORDER BY ts_creado DESC
   LIMIT 10)
  UNION ALL
   (SELECT col1, col2. . .
   FROM carruseles_comentarios
   ORDER BY  ts_creado DESC
   LIMIT 10)
  ) q
JOIN    usuarios u  ON u.id = q.id_usuario
ORDER BY ts_creado DESC
LIMIT   0, 10
```

(This assumes you want the multi-level limits — top ten of the twenty records consisting of the top ten noticias and top ten carruseles).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my question with the code I'm using now, adapting the one you've posted there. Now I get the error: **1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY**. Thank you in advance! // PS: I use the multilevel limits to do a $offset, $limit with PHP to not select all the comments.

Comment: @Isern: I just made a (small) update to my answer to include extra parentheses around the two SELECTs within the UNION, as required by the MySQL documentation.  Please see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Now I get another time the 1271 of "Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'". If you think that there is a better way to do what I'm trying let me know. Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that the error message is correct (possibly q is being created with a different, default, collation).  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about MySQL collation sequences to determine exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

make sure table carruseles_comentarios and noticias_comentarios have same number of columns:
If they have different number of columns try to get only common columns like following:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    (
            SELECT  col1, col2
            FROM  noticias_comentarios
            ORDER BY
                    ts_creado DESC
            LIMIT 10
            ) q
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
            SELECT  col1, col2
            FROM carruseles_comentarios
            ORDER BY
                    ts_creado DESC
            LIMIT 10
            ) q
    ) q
```

Comment: they have, the only change is that to point to the noticias table I use noticias_comentarios.id_noticias and with carruseles I use carruseles_comentarios.id_carrusel but all other are shared